# viewport unit vh is recalculating only on horizontal resize(not vertical). Chrome

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I have a website that relies on viewport sizes in "slide" containers, but after vertical resize of window heights are not recalculated. Horizontal and mixed scrolls forces to recalculate `vh` in right order. `vw` is recalculated correctly on horizontal resize.

Can I fix it or make a js enforcer of recalculation of re-render on resize?

Chrome 30, mac os x 10.9.

Comment: Interesting. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/MpEX2/2/show/) but it doesn't recalculate, not even when resizing horizontally. Only when refreshing. Hm. I think it's a bug. Works fine in FF and IE.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will force viewport units to be recalculated on resize...

```
var altcrement = -1;
$(window).resize(function(){
    var currentFontSize = parseFloat($('html').css('font-size'));
    $('html').css('font-size', currentFontSize + (altcrement *= -1) + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery plugin:
https://github.com/draashurx/viewportfontsize

Easily implemented:

```
$('p').vw(10); // Equals to css font-size: 10vw;
$('p').vh(5);  // Equals to css font-size: 5vh;
```

It also recalculates perfectly. Non browser-dependent. So guarantee to work (with jQuery library).